# Generalized rational form

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix a field $k$. It is well known that any square matrix is similar to a block-diagonal matrix such that every block is of the following form: $1$ in the subdiagonal, a bunch of numbers in the last column of the block and $0$ everywhere else.

I am curious about the following: what if instead of allowing conjugation by arbitrary matrices, we allow only conjugation by those of the form

\begin{pmatrix} P & Q \\ 0 & R \end{pmatrix}

where $P$ and $R$ are invertible square matrices, and $P$ is $r\times r$, for some fixed $r\leq n$? What are the normal forms in this case? What "dimension" does the space of normal forms have? (e.g., for the rational form, we need $n$ parameters to describe all normal forms)